# No internet access on VM bridged to Hamachi network interface

Tags: vmware, internet-connection, hamachi

I am using Windows 7 and am using a 3G USB adapter to connect to the internet.I set up a Windows XP virtual machine in VMWare and Hamachi on the Windows 7 PC. Hamachi works properly on the Windows 7 machine.

With the Windows XP VM, I set the Network Adapter to Bridged and bridge it to Hamachi the Network Adapter (virtual network adapter on the real PC) through Virtual Network Editor.

VMware Bridge Protocol is checked in Hamachi Network Adapter. However, i get notice from Network connection (in the Windows XP VM) "Limited or no connectivity..." I think this means that I can't connect to the internet through the "Hamchi Network Interface" or maybe unable I am unable to get DHCP addresses?

So, how can I bridge the VM to my Hamachi Network Interface in order to connect to the Internet?